# Git Stashing and Branching

Tags: git

All,
  I just had a major mishap with git and I'm very confused on what happened/what I did wrong.

I had two files that I've been working on: `classA.cpp` and `classA.h`. I needed to merge with a coworker. So...

```
git stash
git pull origin master
```

Now I have the newest work from my coworker. I get my changes from the stash.

```
git stash pop
```

At this point, I'm thinking I should be using git correctly, so I endeavor to make a new branch.

```
git branch MyChange
git checkout MyChange
git status
```

Git status shows my two (unstaged) modified files.

```
git checkout master
git status
```

Git status shows (again) the two unstaged modified files.

```
git checkout -- .
```

Git status shows that the modified files have been rewound.

```
git checkout MyChange
```

MODIFIED FILES ARE REWOUND!?!? WHAT THE HECK!?! Where did my thoughts go wrong, I thought changing branches would not affect the other branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did *not* change the branch, you did change your working tree. And new files / changes that were neither added to the Staging Area nor to a Commit are not tracked and not preserved by git.

Comment: The files were tracked though. Modified but no staged for committing.

Comment: So I had to at least to git add [modified files], THEN switch back? Until then both branches point to the same point in history?

Comment: @Constantin Unless you somehow preserve your changes in git your working tree is volatile as git does not know about the changes.

Comment: Okay eclipse just saved my life, it had a local history since I opened one of the files recently. Could you show me the commands I need to create two branches correctly? Note I don't want to commit in the other branch yet as the code is incomplete and will not compile.

Comment: Okay I did git add, but the files are still present as modified in master. My goal is make a copy of master without my changes, pop my changes into the copy, then switch back to master which does not have my changes.

Comment: Interstingly even thought I did git add in MyChange, the changes are staged in both branches (MyChange and master). This makes no sense.